# Three.js custom shader material and texture not blending, the rest of the scene is

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: blending failure]

In my Three.js scene, on certain angles, my texture stops blending with other textures, all other items keep working? Any idea? I use a custom shader to remote green-screen pixels.

I tried turning on different blending modes, like this:

```js
material.blending = THREE.CustomBlending
material.blendSrc = THREE.OneFactor
material.blendDst = THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor
```

Comment: I think i need to write the depth buffer in my shader.

Comment: You must add the solution to an answer, but not to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by discarding the fragment if the alpha is 0.0. I know this is not the most correct solution. But it works for me. Setting the gl_fragDepth to 1 if alpha is nearing 0.0 also works.